# Android Studio & NDK: I got an error when "javah -d jni -classpath..."

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio

The Point:

I want to call a C/C++ function from Java.

What I do:

1

I followed this direction. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fEtrekNcOo

Just created Project, wrote below code and build it.

```
public native String HelloJNI();
static {
    System.loadLibrary("HelloJNI");
}
```

2

```
javah -d jni -classpath /Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar;../../build/intermediates/classes/debug com.test.ndktest.MyActivity
```

The Problem:

I got this error message. "bash: ../../build/intermediates/classes/debug: is a directory"

I spent many time to find solutions.. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

- C/C++ will be used for obfuscation of my code. I will hide some API keys in C/C++ code.
- I watched another video but I could not find any solutions.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okLKfxfbz40

Comment: Try terminating /classes/debug with a /. Does it indeed contain your compiled package?

Comment: @Seva Alekseyev Thanks your comment. I tried '/' but not work.

Comment: I can see some compiled classes in ../../build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/test/ndktest/

Comment: look at delimiter u use in classpath...   ":  or ; "   You can CD to the parent of your package's classes and invoke 'javah' from there. wont need the multiple CP expression then

Comment: @Robert Rowntree It worked!! I changed from ";" to ":". Thanks and I am sorry my stupid mistake.

Comment: I could .h file. I may be able to proceed next step. Thanks again. If you post the answer, I can close this question.

Comment: I watched the video which used ';'... anyway I will proceed to next

Comment: did you ever get this working?