# Android NDK "Error: Could not find class file.." Android Studio & Windows 7

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I have a problem with Android NDK to Make the following command ... I have installed NDK and complimented ...

```
C:\Users\Eduu\AndroidStudioProjects\ndk>javah -jni -classpath C:\Users\Eduu\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar;bin\classes\ -d jni\ com.example.eduu.ndk.MainActivity
Error: Could not find class file for 'com.example.eduu.ndk.MainActivity'.
```

Link Tutorial: Step 3.3 https://geekytheory.com/hola-mundo-con-android-ndk-parte-4/

Thanks.

Comment: When you work with NDK, keep using direct slashes **`/`**, not back slashes **`\\`**

Comment: I tried but still the same error

Comment: This could be a spelling error, or you are looking at the wrong directory. Please check `dir /s bin\classes\*.class`… Wait a second… Are you working in Android Studio?

Comment: Yes (?) And Windows 7

Comment: possible duplicate of *[Android Studio & NDK: I got an error when “javah -d jni -classpath…”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252712/android-studio-ndk-i-got-an-error-when-javah-d-jni-classpath)* and *[Javah still won't find class files in OSX / Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274155/javah-still-wont-find-class-files-in-osx-android-studio)*

Answer (score 1):

The path `bin\classes\` is specific for Eclipse project structure. With the default structure of Android Studio project, your command line should look like

```
C:\Users\Eduu\AndroidStudioProjects\ndk>javah -jni -classpath C:/Users/Eduu/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar;app/build/intermediates/classes/debug -d app/src/main/jni com.example.eduu.ndk.MainActivity
```

Note that I use forward slash everywhere, to avoid glitches. Also, both paths to **jni** directory and to the **classes** directory that I use above, are *default* paths for Android Studio. These may change per project. You should manually look for the directory where your **.cpp** files are an where the compiler puts the **.class** files, whenever you have suspicion that the paths may be different.

Comment: Thanks, did not work but I'm taking another tutorial more updated with Android Studio 2015

Answer (score 0):

Another Simple solution for build class in android studio is

In terminal,

```
cd app/src/main
```

then,

`javah -d jni -classpath ../../build/intermediates/classes/debug` *location of class file*